# Why Facebook has a user id for each app?

Tags: facebook

In Facebook Explorer Tools, I request user information from many apps. Older apps answer me the same user ID. A recent created app answers another one. I access http://facebook.com/ with both ids and all of them redirects me to my account.

When did Facebook change this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the apps "answer me" a user id?

Comment: /me returns my basic information, like name and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was changed on 4/30/2014 and what you are seeing are app scoped user id. You can read more about it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/